# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the printer in Mac printer dialog boxes?

Tags: macos, keyboard, ui

I want to jump to the printer selector with the keyboard and select the desired printer with the keyboard.

Comment: When I bring up the print dialog (Cmd + P), the printer drop-down menu is already selected, so I can then press the down arrow until I select the printer I want, press Enter to select it, then Enter again to print it. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: It's true--didn't know that 'til I read the below though :P Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most applications pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> brings up the printer dialog sheet, which uses standard tab and or arrow key navigation.

The printer dialog sheet has two views.

- Show Details view, which means the Hide Details button is visible.
- Hide Details view, which means the Show Details button is visible.

When it opens in the Show Details view, having the Hide Details button visible, the Printer: list box has focus and one can immediately press the up or down arrow keys to select between which installed printer, Add Printer... and: Print & Scan Preferences...

[image: Show Details view]

In the image above, pressing either the up or down arrow keys brings up the printer list box, as shown in the cropped image below, where one can select between which installed printer, Add Printer... and: Print & Scan Preferences...

---

[image: Printer List Box]

---

When it opens in the Hide Details view, having the Show Details button visible, the Copies: text box has focus and one then needs to use tab key navigation to set focus to the Printer: list box and then press the up or down arrow keys to select which installed printer, Add Printer... and: Print & Scan Preferences...

[image: Hide Details view]

In the image above, pressing the tab key several times (4 times) will bring the Printer: list box into focus where one can then press the up or down arrow keys brings up the printer list box, shown as an example previously above.

Comment: Fantastic! Argh, I can't believe I didn't try pressing up/down arrow--I guess I'm used to seeing something indicating what control has the focus!

Comment: @ajg23, As you can see in the first image the Printer: list box has focus and a blue highlight and in the third picture the Copies: text box has focus and a blue highlight. Theses are the default controls in the two different views of the Printer dialog sheet.

Answer (score 5):

Add a new shortcut to System Prefences > Keyboard > Shortcut > App Shortcuts.

Choose an existing printer name (in my example *Lexa* - a Lexmark printer, a Kyocera is my default printer) and enter a shortcut:

[image: Keyboard Prefs]

To print with this (obviously non-default) printer enter <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, and once the Print dialog displays, enter <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to switch to the other printer:

[image]

To print with your default printer just use the common <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: It's not global, it's only relevant to the Print dialog.